# c# protobuf System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

I am using Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10, .Net Framework 4.8. (if you need more info ask)

I have a `model.proto` file that compiles into `Model.pb.cs`, and I use in my project.

When I fill the model with data and try to save it into a file ....

```
using PMOD = MyProtobuf.Model;

using NLog;
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

var req = PMOD.MyDataModel();
// fill up req with all data ...
using (var file_output = File.Create("path/to/save/PB/file/into")) {
   using (var stream_output = new Google.Protobuf.CodedOutputStream(file_output)) {
      req.WriteTo(stream_output); <---- this one gives errors
   }
}
```

This happens.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

this is my `program.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <Protobuf Include="../../protobuf/model.proto" Link="model.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="3.0.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.15.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="2.36.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="MathNet.Numerics" Version="4.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MathNet.Spatial" Version="0.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NetMQ" Version="4.0.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  etc etc ... with files to compile
```

Comment: Does adding reference help? [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/)

Comment: the reference in question would be this `<PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="5.0.0" />` but the runtime can't find it anyway.

Comment: This assembly is a known pain point and usually requires assembly binding redirects; see https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/ - or better: *use .NET 5* (or later) - .net framework (4.8 etc) is end-of-life

Comment: thanks Marc. I can't use .Net 5 because is not compatible with one of the main DLLs I use. I tried this as my `app.config`. the issues is still there.

<assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.1" newVersion="5.0.0"/>